# How do I get ng-options to run a function on select?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to have my controller do a couple things when a user selects a value in a drop down.

edit: 1.3 offers the `getterSetter` `ngModelOption`, but I need to use 1.2.x. Edited to remove mistaken 1.3-compatible code.

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="selectedThing" 

        ng-options="thing.name for thing in allThings">
</select>
```

Comment: SHouldn't it be `getterSetter` s in caps?

Comment: Works for me.. http://plnkr.co/edit/o2AuIl?p=preview You have some other issue check your console for any errors. Well did the angular version that you are use support it? Try replicate your issue in a plunker

Comment: No errors in the console, which is odd.  I'm playing with your plunker now.

Comment: Which version of angular you are using?

Comment: Cummon man it is not supported in 1.2 version. Did you not even check before using it.. :/ ?

Comment: What is not supported?

Comment: getterSetter, [Did you check the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

Comment: I guess you're right. I didn't realize the docs were defaulting to a beta version.

Question updated to reflect 1.2-ness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## For 1.2.x

Only way to do this seems to be `$watch`ing the `$scope.selectedThing`:

```
$scope.selectedThing = aThing;

$scope.$watch('selectedThing', function () {
     //do stuff here
});
```

Once you select a value in the dropdown, this will trigger.

## For 1.3-beta

If you want to avoid `$watch`ing a variable, then you can use the forthcoming `ngModelOptions`:

```
<select ng-model="selectedThing" 
        ng-model-options="{getterSetter:true}" 
        ng-options="thing.name for thing in allThings">
```

And in your controller:

```
currentThing = aThing;

$scope.selectedThing = function (newThing) {
    if (angular.isDefined(newThing)) {
        console.log("setting new Thing", newThing);
        currentThing = newThing;
        
    }
    return currentThing;
};
```